# SpeechRecognition Python package does not listen

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I installed [SpeechRecognition](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition) for python3 on a Windows 10 machine. When running `python -m speech_recognition` in the terminal, it says:

```
A moment of silence, please...
Set minimum energy threshold to 969.0670687586011
Say something!
```

Yet, it detects no acoustic signal at all even though I double checked the microphone to be turned on.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just curious: what module are you using to do this?

Comment: @AaronBrandhagen https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition

Comment: Thanks for this!