# Cannot get audio through speech_recognition python by any method?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I am try to make [`SpeechRecognition 3.8.1`](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) listen to my voice for four days. I have already seen the following stuff in the internet:

1. https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/20
2. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/voice-assistant-using-python/
3. https://pythonrepo.com/repo/Uberi-speech_recognition-python-audio

   - `sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio python3-pyaudio` does not work for me.
4. [speech recognition python code not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005310/speech-recognition-python-code-not-working)
5. [Errors on PyAudio on Visual studio code Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61256699/errors-on-pyaudio-on-visual-studio-code-python)
6. [I can't install pyaudio on Windows? How to solve "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840/i-cant-install-pyaudio-on-windows-how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14)
7. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50424902/speechrecognition-python-package-does-not-listen?r=SearchResults&s=4|89.4428](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50424902/speechrecognition-python-package-does-not-listen?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C89.4428)
8. https://newbedev.com/speech-recognition-python-code-not-working-code-example
9. https://www.py4u.net/discuss/22062

I have gone through many more discussions, **ALL IN VAIN**.

 No solution worked for me till now. Please help!!

After a lot of unsuccessful attempts, I have at least managed to install `pyaudio` with the command `pipwin install pyaudio`

my python code:

```py
import os
import pyttsx3, datetime, pyaudio
import speech_recognition as sr

# Initial Setup for pyttsx3 - speaking abilities
engine = pyttsx3.init("sapi5")
voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
engine.setProperty("voice", voices[1].id)  # 0-male voice , 1-female voice
sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()

# Initial Setup for speech_recognition - listening abilities
# r.energy_threshold = 10
# print(pyaudio.get_device_count() - 1)


def speak(speakable):
    """speak() takes a string and reads it loud"""
    engine.say(str(speakable))
    engine.runAndWait()


def takeCommand():
    pyaudio.PyAudio()
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    """It takes microphone input from the user and returns string output"""
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.9)
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 45
        audio = ""
        try:
            audio = r.listen(source)
            print("Recognizing...")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Listen err: ", e)
        try:
            print("Recognizing...")
            query = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(f"User said: {query}\n")  # User query will be printed.
        except sr.UnknownValueError as e:
            print("Say that again please...")
            return "None"  # None string will be returned
        except Exception as err:
            print("Check your internet...")
            return "None"
    return query


def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour >= 0 and hour < 12:
        speak("Good Morning!")

    elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
        speak("Good Afternoon!")

    else:
        speak("Good Evening!")
        speak(
            "Hello Sir, I am Friday, your Artificial intelligence assistant. Please tell me how may I help you"
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.system("CLS")
    while True:
        command = takeCommand().lower()
        print(f"Command: {command}")
        if "wish" in command:
            wishMe()
```

the output gets stuck at `Listening...`. Nothing happens after that.

### More Info:

1. I am using `Windows 10 Home`
2. Code editor- `vs code`
3. I am not using `virtual env` in this this program.
4. I have also checked that **Chrome Voice Search** is working without any trouble.
5. [image: python3 -m speech_recognition] result of the `python3 -m speech_recognition` command

Comment: please at least tell me where I can ask about this issue

Comment: IS there any other package or any other way to achieve my goal???

Comment: please share advice if you know about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with the `python3 -m speech_recognition`? You should see something like:

```
...
A moment of silence, please...
Set minimum energy threshold to 51.208131879528096
Say something!
Got it! Now to recognize it...
You said hello
```

If that does not work, you probably have something wrong with your audio system. Make sure that you can record your audio (https://onlinehardwaretest.com/microphone-test/) and consider rebooting your system.

Comment: I have done this, but still not positive result even though I got what you have mentioned

Comment: I have rebooted and I have also checked my drivers and updated them

Comment: I just now checked my audio with the link you provided, it is well and fine

Answer (score 0):

when I comment the lines:

```
def takeCommand():
  .....
 with sr.Microphone() as source:
        #  --> r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.9) 
        print("Listening...")
        #  -->  r.pause_threshold = 45 
...
```

Works for me.